# Deleted answer still appears in app's feed

Tags: bug, android-app, android-app-feed

The following "answer" was deleted many days ago, but it still appears in the  feed. The "answer" also remained in my notifications after it was deleted.

[image]

- App Version: 1.0.89

Comment: This happens often on my iOS-app, which still notifies me of replies on deleted posts on the feed page.

Comment: I believe it's simply because the feed isn't retroactive (i.e. once something's in the feed it's there for good... stuff is added but not taken away).